# Why isn't my property being updated inside the "Scope"?

Tags: angular, firebase, ecmascript-6

I am starting to venture into Angular2 for a hobby project and have run into something I don't know how to debug or search for yet.

I started out using the [ng2-play](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play) repository.

I have two simple classes (this code is drastically simplified for this post):

words-ui.js

```
export class WordsUI {
  constructor() {
    new Words(data => this.words = data);
  }
}
```

words-ui.html

```
<ol *if="words" reversed>
  <li *for="#entry of words" title="Word for week starting {{entry.date}}">{{entry.word}}</li>
</ol>
```

words-data.js

```
export class Words {
  constructor(cb) {
    firebase
      .child('words')
      .on('value', data => cb(data.val()));
  }
}
```

The only thing that isn't working correctly yet is the "scope" recognizing that the value of the property `words` has been updated. This means that when the UI loads nothing is shown in the list of words. If I then add a word to the list through the UI all words, plus the added word, show up. Or, if I put in a setTimeout to "reload" the `words` property with it's own value they show up.

I imagine that I am not using the right pattern for this but where would I find out what pattern would be better for this situation. I am a little lost in the new ES6 module system as well as: TypeScript and AngularJS 2.

I think I have provided the relevant portions of code to illustrate the problem but if not please let me know and I can work on putting together something better.

UPDATE 1: Added view file. The change to `words` on the "context" of `WordsUI` instance aren't reflected.

Comment: I don't really see where the `$scope` comes into play in your code?

Comment: There is no $scope in Angular 2. Can you show your views please including all the template html?

Comment: When I said "scope" above I was referring to "context" or `this`. I think I found the "fix"/"workaround". The problem may have been that the callback inside of the constructor wasn't triggering any dirty checking (I think). Once I moved the code out of the constructor things started working as expected.

Comment: @kalisjoshua If you've solved your question it would be great to post an answer for someone else who may have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and the suggestion to post the answer I found. @chic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found an answer - or work around, depending on your point of view - to this situation a few hours after running into it originally. The final repository for this hobby project is on [GitHub Weekly Word](https://github.com/kalisjoshua/weekly-word).

### The Problem

I was essentially attempting to set a property on the WordsUI instance from within the callback passed to the Word constructor. I think somehow that was not being picked up but the "scope watcher" `zones.js` (I think).

### The Resolution

I moved the reading of data, from the Word instance, into a subsequent call from the instance; rather than trying to be tricky and keeping that in the callback passed to the constructor.

I don't think that this approach - the one I ended up using - is inferior necessarily, nor was the former superior really in any way.

words-ui.js

```
export class WordsUI {
  constructor() {
    this words = new Words();
    this.update();
  }

  update() {
    this.words
        .read(words => {
            this.wordList = words;
        })
  }
}
```

words-data.js

```
export class Words {
  constructor() {
    firebase = new Firebase('http://weekly-word.firebase.com').child('words');
  }

  read(cb) {
    firebase
        .on('value', data => {
            cb(data);
        })
  }
}
```